# oath implicit grant flow client on java or c#

Tags: security, token, implicit, adfs3.0

Is it possible to request a security token on java or C# from AD FS using implicit grant flow ? It looks like that is only possible in JS (in a browser). Thank you  in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS 3.0 only supports authorization code grant.

ADFS vNext (Server 2016) will support this.

Azure AD also supports this currently.